# Loop based on identification number

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to generate all the transition matrixes based on id. How can I loop my data to calculate the transitions based on id? Example below is for id 1, I would like to have all matrixes till id 5

Example of code that incorporates markov transition calculations:

```
  Ep<-as.matrix(Activities[1:1,2:4])
    
    
    trans.matrix <- function(X, prob=T)
    {
      tt <- table( c(X[,-ncol(X)]), c(X[,-1]) )
      if(prob) tt <- tt / rowSums(tt)
      as.matrix(tt)
    }
    
    Ep<-trans.matrix(as.matrix(Ep))
```

Data structure:

[image]

Sample data:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), a = c(0, 2, 2, 3, 1), b = c(1, 
3, 3, 2, 2), c = c(1, 4, 4, 3, 3), d = c(0, 5, 3, 2, 4)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), b = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), c = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), d = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over the rows

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(Activities)),
      function(i) {
   tmp <- trans.matrix(as.matrix(Activities[i, 2:4]))
   write.csv(tmp, file =  paste0(i, ".csv"), quote = FALSE)
        })
```